# Calculate columns from database then pull into table cell

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

EDIT: I have successfully been able to calculate the value I was trying to get, but instead of calculating that value for each row, it is just calculating it once and posting that value everywhere.  How do I make it recalculate for each row using the code I have?

Picture: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/9064/example2w.png

New Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP-MySQL Project 4</title>

    <div align="center">
        <p>
            PHP-MySQL Project 4
        <br/>
            By: Ryan Strouse
        </p>
    </div>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#99FFFF">

<?php

$DBName = "surveys";
$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password")
    Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
    . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";

if (!$DBConnect)
    {
    echo "<p> The database server is not available.</p>";
    }
else
    {
    echo "<p> Successfully connected to the database $DBName</p>";
    }

mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName); 
echo "<p>Database -'$DBName'- found</p>";

$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM surveys WHERE surveyCode = 'GEI001'";
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
echo $SQLstring;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);

$count_surveys = $row['surveyResponses'];

echo "<p>Total Responses: $count_surveys</p>";


$SQLstring2 = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE surveyCode = 'GEI001'";
$QueryResult2 = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring2);
echo $SQLstring2;
echo "<br/>";
$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult2);


$SQLstring3 = "SELECT * FROM surveys, results";
$QueryResult3 = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring3);
$fetchrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult3);
$result_amount = (($fetchrow['resultResponses'] / $fetchrow['surveyResponses']) * 100);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Commercial</th> <th>Views</th> <th>Percentage</th></tr>";
do {
    echo "<tr><td>{$Row['resultDescription']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['resultResponses']}</td>";
    echo "<td>$result_amount</td></tr>";
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult3);
} while ($Row);
echo "</table>";


?>



<center>
<h3><a href="Survey1.html">Return To Main Page</a></h3>
<h3><a href="../Menu.html">Return to Menu</a></h3>
</center>
</body>

<footer>
<div align="center">
&copy; Copyright Ryan Strouse &copy;

</div>
</footer>
</html>
```

I have two database tables and I am successfully pulling in column data into a table.  The third cell of the table I would like to calculate a percentage out of some of the columns from the database.  I'm not sure how to code this... I've tried to come up with something in the SELECT statement from another thread I found with no luck.

Here is a picture of the query I'm trying to get to work: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/3862/examplegw.png

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP-MySQL Project 4</title>


</head>
<body bgcolor="#99FFFF">

<?php

$DBName = "surveys";
$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password")
    Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
    . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
    . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";

if (!$DBConnect)
    {
    echo "<p> The database server is not available.</p>";
    }
else
    {
    echo "<p> Successfully connected to the database $DBName</p>";
    }

mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName); 
echo "<p>Database -'$DBName'- found</p>";

$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM surveys WHERE surveyCode = 'GEI001'";
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
echo $SQLstring;
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);

$count_surveys = $row['surveyResponses'];

echo "<p>Total Responses: $count_surveys</p>";


$SQLstring2 = "SELECT * FROM results WHERE surveyCode = 'GEI001'";
$QueryResult2 = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring2);
echo $SQLstring2;
echo "<br/>";
$Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult2);


//this is where I am trying to calculate the value and then below it display in table 
//cell # 3
$SQLstring3 = "SELECT *,((resultResponses/surveyResponses)*100) AS AMOUNT FROM surveys, results";
$QueryResult3 = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring3);

do {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th>Commercial</th> <th>Views</th> <th>Percentage</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>{$Row['resultDescription']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$Row['resultResponses']}</td>";
    echo "<td>$QueryResult3</td></tr>";
    $Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
} while ($Row);
echo "</table>";


?>



<center>
<h3><a href="Survey1.html">Return To Main Page</a></h3>
<h3><a href="../Menu.html">Return to Menu</a></h3>
</center>
</body>

<footer>

</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: This is vague, you haven't given any example code of what you are trying to calculate percentages of. What have you tried? What is the data coming from the db, etc..

Comment: @SamuelCook I have edited and provided picture if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF** I understand what you are asking, you're trying probably to calculate the percentage of a value that you can find in a MySQL query's results. If that is so, then I'd use the function `mysql_num_rows` to get the total of the records and then in a `while` and `if` I'd have a counter of how many times I meet that value.

Then you just do simple math, for example:

```
result = (100 * counter) / mysql_num_rows
```

and have a percentage. Then you just `echo` the result wherever you want! :)

I hope I have understood your question correctly!

Comment: Close, I'm trying to calculate a percentage based on dividing two columns from separate tables.  Both columns are set up as INT.  My SELECT statement returns a NULL instead of a value.

Comment: Here is a picture of the result if it helps: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/3862/examplegw.png

Comment: Are the columns `surveyResponses` and `resultResponses` of an arithmetic type? Also, if you get the error in MySQL results, then since you are selecting the values anyway, make the math equation in PHP instead of the MySQL.
`$result_amount = ($result['resultResponses'] / $result['surveyResponses']) * 100;`

Comment: Getting an error "Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array "

My code is $result_amount = ($QueryResult3['resultResponses'] / $QueryResult3['surveyResponses']) * 100;

Comment: Both columns are set as INT(7) so I should be able to perform arithmetic on them

Comment: Actually, it is just calculating the first row, and then inputting that value everywhere I am calling it.  Here is a picture: http://img515.imageshack.us/img515/9064/example2w.png

Comment: I have updated the original question with the code I am now using.

Comment: I worked it around enough to work! Thanks so much for your suggestions, it gave me the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT yourRow FROM yourTable");
$aArray = array();
$cont=0;
while($col = mysql_fetch_assoc($result){
   $aArray[$cont] = $col['yourRow'];
   cont++;
}
```

That should give you a workable array for you to make your math with it and then echo it. Cheers

Comment: Not sure how to work the array to get the math involved, could you show me a bit more?

Comment: You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php and   http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php and have fun with the percentages